Google StreetView Api's
I'm trying to display a streetview based on coordonates ( latlng ) or even panoramaid using google's apis. I'm stucked on a problem where loading streetview with their streetview api shows in network the response to their api, which is a metadata showing all the informations regarding the location loaded.
One approach i took was to download 6 images to form a cube into pannellum and serve on the site, but this is violating google's TC as they considering that what i'm doing is manipulating the photos.
Downloading directly the tiles as said here ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/streetview?hl=en ) and using their custom viewer is an option, but still getmetadata is received with informations about the specific location.
My question is : has everyone tried and succeeded displaying a panoramic streetview ( without movement back&forth -- as this implies getting coordonates or panoramaid for a differnet location and metadata is downloaded ) without having all the metadat received ?
I currently looking for alternatives to display a streetview panorama, where users can rotate on a specific location but not move back&forth, and also not having all the informations regarding that location received in inspect.
Thank you
Everything tried is already posted in initial message.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
